# LDAP with starttls on redmine

Tags: ldap, redmine, starttls

Redmine does not use StartTLS by default. When I configure my LDAP server to require TLS, redmine fails to authenticate users.

With openldap you might see "Confidentially required" error message in redmine logs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure LDAPS is NOT enabled. ldaps:// is a different encryption scheme than StartTLS. With StartTLS unecrypted connection is promoted to encrypted over same port.

When using redmine 3.2.4 find a file with name redmine/app/models/auth_source_ldap.rb

search for "encryption", find:

```
 options = { :host => self.host,
            :port => self.port,
            :encryption => (self.tls ? :simple_tls : nil)
          }
```

When LDAPS is unchecked, we want to use StartTLS:

```
:encryption => (self.tls ? :simple_tls : :start_tls)
```

Save and restart your web server. Redmine should now use encrypted connection.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I just had a similar problem but with Redmine 4.1.2.

I had to make a similiar change to get StartTLS to work without LDAPS:

in redmine/app/models/auth_source_ldap.rb

Search for this block of code

```
if tls
      options[:encryption] = {
        :method => :simple_tls,
        # Always provide non-empty tls_options, to make sure, that all
        # OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS as well as the default cert
        # store are used.
        :tls_options => { :verify_mode => verify_peer? ? OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER : OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE }
      }
```

and update it with the an else clause as:

```
if tls
      options[:encryption] = {
        :method => :simple_tls,
        # Always provide non-empty tls_options, to make sure, that all
        # OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS as well as the default cert
        # store are used.
        :tls_options => { :verify_mode => verify_peer? ? OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER : OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE }
      }
    else
      options[:encryption] = {
        :method => :start_tls,
        :tls_options => { :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}
      }
    end
```